# Wrapper class wrapping multiple types and composition pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, composition

I have a wrapper class as following which wraps TypeA,TypeB and TypeC.

```
class Wrapper
{
    class TypeA {get;set;}
    class TypeB {get;set;}
    class TypeC{get;set;}
}
```

Now caller code is not good because of this. As I have to determine based on the different types like this:

```
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(TypeA);

if (wrapper.TypeA != null && wrapper.TypeA.SomeProperty != null)
{
    return wrapper.TypeA.SomeProperty;
}

if (wrapper.TypeB != null && wrapper.TypeB.SomeProperty != null)
{
    return wrapper.TypeB.SomeProperty;
}

Wrapper cwrapper = new Wrapper(TypeA, TypeB);

if (wrapper.TypeA == null && wrapper.TypeB != null && wrapper.TypeB.SomeProperty != null)
{
    return wrapper.TypeB.SomeProperty;
}
```

As you see, the caller code has to check for lot of combination of TypeA and TypeB and TypeC as well. 
I was just thinking to use some composition and expose some strategy or property which will give me desired object such as:

`wrapper.As<TypeA>()` or something. Any suggestion how to avoid this multiple checks from the caller part?

Comment: Can it wrap multiple objects at the same time?

Comment: Do Types A, B and C implement the same interface?

Comment: Do the properties have exactly the same name in each type. Is there a corresponding property for each property in each type? How many properties will you need to access like this?

Comment: Yes it can wrap multiple object at the same time and it has bunch of other properties with different names.

Answer (score 2):

Why? You are using kind a `Adapter Pattern` and your class should look like

```
class Wrapper
{
    public TypeA A {get;set;}
    public TypeB B {get;set;}
    public TypeC C{get;set;}

  public Wrapper(TypeA A, TypeB B, TypeC C)
  {
   this.A = A;
   // rest initialization
  }
}
```

You can now just say

```
Wrapper w = new Wrapper(new TypeA(), ...);
w.A.SomeProperty;
```

Again, instead of that null check `if` condition you can use *Null Propagation* operator like

```
wrapper?.TypeA?.SomeProperty;
```

You can use a *Null Coalesce* operator together in-order to return a default value of property in case property is null

```
wrapper?.TypeA?.SomeProperty ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some guard clauses in your constructor and some readonly properties to tidy all this up

```
class Wrapper
{
    public TypeA A {get;}
    public TypeB B {get;}
    public TypeC C {get;}

  public Wrapper(TypeA A, TypeB B, TypeC C)
  {
   this.A = A ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(A));
   this.B = B ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(B));
   this.C = C ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(C));
  }
}
```

Now unless someone has done something silly with reflection your A,B,C properties can't be null. So you don't need to null check.

You can then use the null-coalescing operator to tidy up the last bits

```
wrapper.A.someProperty ?? string.Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you suggested, I would use a type of cast convenience method. Something like this:

```
class Wrapper {
    bool TryGet<T> (out T wrappedObj) {
        if (typeof(T) == ClassA.GetType()) {
            wrappedObj = objA;
        }
        //...
        return wrappedObj != null;
    }

    // or
    bool TryGet<T,U>(Func<U> propGetter, out U prop) {
        if (TryGet<T>(out T wrappedObj)) {
            prop = propGetter(wrappedObj);
            return true;
        }
        prop = default(U); 
        return false;
    }
}

if (wrapper.TryGet<ClassA>(out ClassA obj)) {
//...
}

//or

if (wrapper.TryGet<ClassA, String>(aObj =>  aObj?.SomeProperty, out String prop) {

}
```